# Send MMS with Bitmap from code

Tags: java, android

I would like to send a `Bitmap` and some text by clicking on a button in a fragment and I would like to let the user choose the contact/number in his messaging app.

How I could do that ?

**EDIT :**

After trying something, I got an error in the message app (Messenger on the emulator) :

> Messenger failed to load attachment.

Here is the code I used :

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Improov/LatestShare.png";
File file = new File(path);
FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".com.example.mous.improov_flash", file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is rather broad. What particular aspect of the problem do you want this question to focus on? The button? The fragment? The text? The `Bitmap`? The user choosing the contact? Getting the phone number of the contact? Sending an MMS?

Comment: @CommonsWare well, I guess using an intent to launch the sms activity with a pre-populated sms/mms with the bitmap I want to send

Answer (score 0):

If you like to send MMS,

First, you should store your bitmap in sd card, then use the following intent to send the MMS,

Get the Uri for your stored bitmap

```
Uri uri = [uri for your stored bitmap];

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
inetnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", [Text to be send]);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
getActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

For more detail read this [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Comment: Thank you but I got an error when I launch the messenger app, I edited my post with the code and the message I have from Messenger

Comment: check for storing bitmap into external storage you have runtime permission or not, and you crash log in your question

Comment: I used FileProvider because of the runtime permission. First I had the error `FileUriExposedException`, that's why I used FileProvider, I find the solution using FileProvider [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

Comment: If you have crash, then add your crash log in your question

Comment: No it's not a crash, there is no error in the log, it's just a Toast message from the application Messenger saying _Messenger failed to load attachment._

Comment: Add **inetnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);** also

Comment: Still not working, I have the same Toast message. I also tried in different app on my phone but it's the same, the app can't open the attached file